# routes.rb explicitly choose template

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, routes

I would like to create one .erb file to be the output for a number of tiny actions that are just returning JSON. So with routes similar to:

```
map.json 'contacts_json', :controller => 'contacts', :action => 'get_json' 
map.json 'cal_json', :controller => 'calendar', :action => 'get_json'
...
```

but this requires I create a contacts erb, and a calendar erb so on and so forth.  Is there a way to explicitly tell them to use a json erb? Something like:

```
map.json 'contacts_json', :controller => 'contacts', :action => 'get_json', :view => 'layouts/json.html.erb'
```

Comment: Why don't you just use the layout and view that you want from your controller actions

..
render :template => 'shared/my.json.erb'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure it answers your question but using render :text => @foobar.to_json does wonders in some cases.

Answer (score 1):

No -- you specify what view template to render in the controller action.